# How can I place a SegmentedControl inside the center of the Navigation Bar by using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I would like to place a SegmentedControl or just a Button inside the center of the NavigationBar by using SwiftUI. I could place it on the trailing and leading part but not in the center.

Answer (score 2):

In SwiftUI 2.0, Xcode 12, You could achieve like below:

```
VStack {
    ....
}
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Picker(selection: $selectionIndex,
               label: EmptyView()) {
            Text("Option 1").tag(0)
            Text("Option 2").tag(1)
         }
         .labelsHidden()
         .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
     }
            
     ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
         leadingNavigationBarItem
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.  `navigationBarTitle(...)` only accepts `Text`.  [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3338325-navigationbartitle).